# Complex routes with more than one id in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

How would you map the following route using Codeigniter 3?

```
/companies/{id}/surveys/{id}/users/{id}
```

As far as I can tell (by reading the docs), only 1 id can be sent to a Controller method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How your controller's method looks like and what parameters uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no matter how many parameters are in your URL. All you have to do is specify your parameter by using `$1`, `$2` respectively for `1st` and then `2nd` parameter and so on. example

```
$route['companies/(:num)/surveys/(:num)/users/(:num)'] = 'company/stat/$1/$2/$3';
```

here `http://localhost/your_project/companies/1/surveys/3/users/32` will goes to `company` controller then `stat` method with `1`, `3` and `32` parameters

hope its helps

Comment: To complete your answer, I found the information about how to retrieve the information from the URL in the docs at http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#passing-uri-segments-to-your-methods, Thanks for your quick answer!!!